# Prove that for all $b\in B$ and $c\in C$, $b+c\in A \, .$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Consider

$A=\{1+5n\mid n\in \mathbb{N} \}$

$B=\{2+5n\mid n\in \mathbb{N} \}$

$C=\{4+5n\mid n\in \mathbb{N} \} .$

Prove that for all $b\in B$ and $c\in C$,  $b+c\in A\, .$

This is what I was thinking...

Suppose $b\in B$ and $c\in C$, then by definition of the sets $ B$ and $C$, $b= 2+5n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $c=4+5m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Now let $a$ be an arbitrary number such that $a=b+c$. Since $b$ and $c$ are both natural numbers, then this implies that $a$ is a natural number. Since $a$ is a natural number, then $a \in A$. Hence $b+c=A$.

Is this how you could prove this?

Comment: Yes it is true that $a$ will be a natural number.  However.... just being a natural number is *not* enough to say that it is an element of $A$ which is a very specific subset of the natural numbers.  This question is very similar to trying to prove that "*an odd number plus an odd number is an even number*."  Take a closer look at your $b$ and $c$ that you chose.  You said that $b=2+5n$ and $c=4+5m$.  So... $b+c=?$ using what you just wrote... $b+c=(2+5n)+(4+5m)$... right?  Now... does that number satisfy the properties of being in $A$?

Comment: "*Since $a$ is a natural number, then $a\in A$*."  Note that $A=\{1,6,11,16,21,26,\dots\}$ and note that many numbers such as $2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,\dots$ are not elements of $A$.

Comment: That all makes sense of why I can't just say because it's a natural number. So, would the correct proof then look like... Suppose $b\in B$ and $c\in C$, then by definition of the sets $ B$ and $C$, $b= 2+5n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $c=4+5m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Now let $a$ be an arbitrary number such that $a=b+c$. Then, $a=b+c$ $a=2+5n + 4 + 5m$ $a= 1+5+5(n+m)$ $a=1+5(1+n+m)$ $a= 1 +5q$ where $q=1+n+m$. Thus $a \in A$ and hence $b+c \in A$.

Comment: You choked.  If b=2+5n  and c=4+5m then a=b+c=6+5n+5m.  (not an "arbitrary" number.)  All you have to do is prove $6+5n+5m\in A $.

Answer (score 2):

> What you said was
>   $$\color{blue}{\text{Since $a$ is a natural number then $a\in A$.}}$$
>   $$\color{red}{\text{Not every natural number belongs to $A$ as $A=\{1,6,11,16,21,26,\cdots\}$.}}$$
>   You could take an easier route

$$a=b+c$$
$$a=2+5n+4+5m$$
$$a=1+5+5(m+n)$$
$$a=1+5(1+m+n)$$
$$a=1+5q$$
$$a\in A$$